# What does an NBA team gain from winning the championship?

Tags: basketball, nba

What does an NBA team gain from winning the championship?

Is the team worth more, or do they get more revenue specifically for the owners?

Answer (score 2):

Teams that win the NBA championship primarily get increased ticket sales in several ways:

- Home ticket sales for each playoff game ([$7-$10 million per game for the Warriors, for example, minus various cuts from TV and the NBA](https://www.insidehook.com/daily_brief/sports/golden-state-warriors-paid-plenty-green-nba-championship)), plus a portion of the [playoff pool](https://www.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/news/accounting-for-basketball-the-money-behind-the-madness/).
- More ticket sales the following year as fans are excited for the team
- More [jersey/apparel sales](https://bluemanhoop.com/2017/06/29/golden-state-warriors-top-jersey-overall-merchandise-sales-list/)

There is no "prize" from the league, however.  The franchise value likely goes up, but there's no direct connection there - it's based on the assumption of the above.  Per [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/teams/golden-state-warriors/?sh=2be8c594f0a7), the value of the Warriors has increased dramatically since their first championship - although all teams have increased significantly, the Warriors' increase was significantly more than other teams over a similar time period (the Warriors are about 10x as valuable now as in 2013, while the Knicks are about 5x, the Bulls are about 4.5x, etc.).

Comment: I get the value of team goes up I was assuming there is some revenue sharing for ticket sell so the team don't benefit.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact rules with tickets, some of the money does go to the NBA, but the home team gets a significant chunk of the ticket sales still.  I've seen various things (and it's probably not totally public knowledge, I don't think any basketball teams are owned by publicly traded companies - MLB we know more about due to ATL and NFL due to the Packers) but the home team keeps something like 30-50% of ticket sales, which can be very significant.